# Middleware for multisite ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-identity-2

**Context**:

In a project, i was given the work to create a middleware that used identity 2 for authentication, replacing the simple membership project they had. I extended roles and user to my like and everything worked good. Now i need to make this middleware, multisite ready.

**Requirements**:

- Each site is treated as a different application;
- Each username is unique, making him possible to login in multisites if he has the permissions for it;
- Every site has their unique roles, and they can have the same name (not description name) as other sites (making the ID the only unique attribute in the role table).
- Every role has their own set of properties, that can and probably will have different values, from other roles with the same name from other sites.

**Idea**:

The way i am thinking on how to tackle this is:

- Since the roles have their ID and it should be unique, there should be no problem in having different roles with the same name (so i would have to remove the uniqueness from the Role Name).
- Each role **belongs** to an application, so a many to one connection between role and application (or site if you want to make it simpler).
- And that's it, that should pretty mutch be simple.

**Problem**:

I have been trying to extend Identity so i could tackle the problem at hands, but it seems i cannot override the uniqueness from the role name with identityDbContext and so, my ApplicationDbContext now inherits DbContext.

**Question**:

I know identity is pretty flexible and that i can possibly tackle this from another angle i am not thinking of right now, since i will have pretty mutch to change usermanager, userstore, rolestore and rolemanager. It's more a question of "am i tackling this the right way", cause so far, i have not found anything about tackling this approach in identity 2.

Thank you for any help!