# Using ASP.NET 5, Identity 2 with custom store and roles with permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity-2

We are developing a non-public business application and will be using ASP.ENT 5 with Identity 2.x! The app will be accessed by employees, managers, both via intranet and internet.
**The big caveat is that we do not want to use AD or Azure AD, as our customers probably do not have that. We also don't need individual logins such as facebook or twitter.**

We need to hook the ASP.NET Identity mechanism up to a legacy database, which has its own entities for roles, users, and permissions.

For starters, there is a tree of "resources" that can be assigned. E.g. a resource would be "Add new product", "Remove product", "Edit product". You can assign a group of users (=role) to one or more such resources.

**My question is how do you hook such a custom scheme up to Identity 2.x?**

There is also not one "admin" role, but many roles on different levels of access that depend on the job/position of the user. A manager (="admin") would create those roles and assign users.

Is there a way to prevent ASP.NET from creating the default dbo.AspNetUsers, etc. tables and instead use the legacy tables?

Is it possible to do split up

```
1. Authentication -> handled by Identity 2 + ASP.NET
2. Authorization -> handled by custom code, e.g. a account controller
```

Does anyone know of resources on this topic?

Comment: Identity is built on top of Entity Framework normally: you can use the same mechanisms you would use on EF to control which tables are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is that possibility ofcourse. What you are looking for is a way to have the identity 2 mechanics but use your own mapping.

You can look at this question for answers: [ASP.NET Identity User and Roles in Multisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165928/asp-net-identity-user-and-roles-in-multisite?rq=1) and the following video shows you some info about using existing Db's with identity 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM

I did something similar but for multitenancy purposes. The concept i used was explained in an earlier question i did: [Middleware for multisite ASP.NET Identity 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496594/middleware-for-multisite-asp-net-identity-2)

To be precise, there is no out of the box system that you can use, but Identity 2 is very customizable. In order for you to have your own tables, you have to create a custom DbContext or override the IdentityDbContext. That is the starting point, where the tables being used by the Identity 2 are set.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you that helps a lot. Is it worth using Identity 3.0 (vNEXT) now or stick with 2.2x? Also, how does EF 7.0 affect Identity? Do you know?

Comment: At the moment i am unable to give you a correct answer to those questions, sorry.